# Some garbage characters in Linux terminal

Tags: terminal

My embedded linux app sometimes outputs the text like this:

```
root@variscite /mnt/nfs$ ./test
```

> GPIO_IMX6_C: i=1 cannot open GPIO device file /sys/class/gpio/gð½Å¢
>                                                                      j¤Ôè
>                                                                          Uêêª
>                                                                              eú5¥Jõ¹¹2¥±zåÍ½±Í?:e½½:e½Å¢j¤Ôè
>                          Uêêª
>   2¥±zåÍ½±Í?:e½½:e½åj¤Ôè     eú5¥Jõº¹¹½?zU¹:A%="?
>                         Uêêª
>   2¥±zåÍ½±Í?:e½½:e½åj¤Ôè    eú5¥JõÂ¹¹½?zU¹:A%="?
>                         Uêêª
>   2¥±zåÍ½±Í?:e½½:e½Å¢Âj¤ÔÈªWKV.¤ËR-k®W«U¹:A%="?
>                                        ×¤¬,]Z»Y1
>   DEBUG[0700]: Fan Control Board: Fan control Write byte ...
>   call CreateServerSocket...9600

Set attrib

Any ideas, what could cause this?

Comment: Looks like something you are accessing is encrypted.

Comment: Could be that you are trying to print from a buffer that is not null terminated. For example a buffer that is not big enough to contain `"cannot open GPIO device file /sys/class/gpio/g"`

Answer (score 2):

Your application is printing some garbage. You can't do anything about that except fix the application.

Garbage characters could also be non-ASCII characters printed in the wrong locale, but given that the garbage occurs immediately after a legitimate-looking string and the application doesn't seem to be trying to print non-English text, an application bug is the most likely — quite possibly it's appending garbage to a string because some C code is missing the part where it should add the null terminator at the end of a string buffer.

If the application happens to print certain escape sequences, this could have lasting effects. Try `tput reset` or `reset` to reset the terminal to a default configuration.